# Create database

Tags: mysql, database

I want to create database. I know that I should use the following code:

`mysqladmin -h localhost -u {username} -p create lrs`

I don't know if something should be replaced with username located between '{' and '}' in the above code. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

`mysqladmin -h localhost -u YOURMYSQLUSERNAME -p create lrs`

replacing `YOURMYSQLUSERNAME` with either `root` or an authorized user.

Comment: I tried what you said and got the message `Enter password: 
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user '{root}'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'`.

Comment: Did you configure the database server?  Or is it not your database server?

Comment: are you able to login at all 'mysql -u root -p' does this allow you to open the mysql cli?